# how to create a Heat Map of Products?

Tags: android, android-layout, heatmap

[image]

i have to create a heat map of products which is look exactly like the picture(attached).But the number of products may vary with the requirement.

what i tried so far :
 1. trying to create the same map with dynamic layouts but having problem when No. of products vary in odd number than i have some blank space.
 2. tried some libraries like : AChartEngine, http://androidplot.com/

but still no luck..

Comment: Could you add some information how the area is determined ?
As far as I can see it seems to be : Weighted Volume (Volume * age) / Visible Area

Comment: @throws_exceptions_at_you :  basically area is determined on the basis of percentage(%age). the design here is just a prototype its not according to the volume or anything.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved heading down this way, but you should implement your partitioning strategy yourself because mine is not finished yet:

```
public class RectDrawable extends Drawable {

        public static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 100;
        public static final int DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.BLUE;

        private Point mSize = new Point(100, 100), mOffset = new Point(0, 0);

        private Dimension mDimension = new Dimension();
        private Paint mPaint = new Paint();

        private void setSizeAndOffset(int width, int height, int offsetX, int offsetY) {

            mSize.x = width;
            mSize.y = height;
            mOffset.x = offsetX;
            mOffset.y = offsetY;
        }

        public RectDrawable(int color) {
            mPaint.setColor(color);
        }

        public RectDrawable(int width, int height, int offsetX, int offsetY, int color) {
            this(color);
            mDimension.size.x = width;
            mDimension.size.y = height;
            mDimension.offset.x = offsetX;
            mDimension.offset.y = offsetY;


        }


        public RectDrawable(Point size, Point offset, int color) {
            this(color);
            mDimension.size.x = size.x;
            mDimension.size.y = size.y;
            mDimension.offset.x = offset.x;
            mDimension.offset.y = offset.y;
        }


        public void setStyle(Paint.Style style) {
            mPaint.setStyle(style);
        }

        public void setColor(int color) {
            mPaint.setColor(color);
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

            canvas.drawRect(mDimension.offset.x, mDimension.offset.y, mDimension.offset.x + mDimension.size.x, mDimension.offset.y + mDimension.size.y, mPaint);
        }

        @Override
        public void setAlpha(int i) {
            mPaint.setAlpha(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getOpacity() {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static abstract class DrawInstructionHolder {
        protected float weight;
        protected int color;
    }

    public static class Product extends DrawInstructionHolder {
        private int color;
        private String name;
        private int volume;

        public Product(int color, String name, int volume, float weight) {
            this.color = color;
            this.name = name;
            this.volume = volume;
            if (weight > 1f)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The weight has to be in between the range of 0f to 1f!");
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public int getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(int color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getVolume() {
            return volume;
        }

        public void setVolume(int volume) {
            this.volume = volume;
        }

        public float getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }

        public void setWeight(float weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }


        public static List<Product> getDemoCollection() {

            List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

            products.add(new Product(Color.YELLOW, "Coragen", 190, 0.2f));
            products.add(new Product(Color.RED, "Record", 126, 0.5f));
            products.add(new Product(Color.GREEN, "Furzate", 316, 0.1f));
            products.add(new Product(Color.BLUE, "Ferterra", 190, 0.2f));


            return products;
        }
    }

    public class Dimension {
        public Point size, offset;

        public Dimension() {
            size = new Point();
            offset = new Point();
        }

        public Dimension(Point size, Point offset) {
            this.size = size;
            this.offset = offset;
        }
    }

    public class HeatMapView extends View {
        public DimensionResolveStrategy randomRecDimensionResolveStrategy = new DimensionResolveStrategy() {

            @Override
            public List<Dimension> calculateDimensions(Canvas canvas, List<? extends DrawInstructionHolder> items, int columns) {

                final List<Dimension> dimensions = new ArrayList<Dimension>();
                final int width = canvas.getWidth(), height = canvas.getHeight();
                final Point size = new Point(width, height), offset = new Point();
                final Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
                final float totalSpace = width * height;
                float currentSpace = totalSpace;

                //Trivial cases
                if (items.size() <= 1) {
                    dimensions.add(new Dimension(size, offset));
                    return dimensions;
                }

                //Randomily evaluate the dimensions of the first item
                currentSpace = (int) (items.get(0).weight * totalSpace);
                size.x = random.nextInt((int) (width % currentSpace)) + 1;
                size.y = (int) (currentSpace / size.x);
                dimensions.add(new Dimension(size, offset));

                for (int i = 1; i < items.size(); i++) {

                    //Do your magic here
                }

                return dimensions;
            }
        };

        public List<Product> mProducts = Product.getDemoCollection();
        public DimensionResolveStrategy mDimResolver;
        public List<Dimension> mDimensions;
        private int mColumns = 2;
        private RectDrawable rectDrawable = new RectDrawable(Color.GREEN);

        public HeatMapView(Context context, List dimensions, DimensionResolveStrategy dimensionResolveStrategy) {

            super(context);
            mDimensions = dimensions;
            mDimResolver = dimensionResolveStrategy;
        }

        public HeatMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public HeatMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Dimension dimension;
            mDimensions = mDimResolver.calculateDimensions(canvas, mProducts, mColumns);
            if (mProducts.size() != mDimensions.size())
                throw new IllegalStateException("Arraylengths of drawing instructions and dimensions are not matching, " +
                        "look into your calculateDimensions(..) function of your DimensionResolveStrategy instance! ");

            for (int i = 0; i < mProducts.size(); i++) {
                dimension = mDimensions.get(1);
                rectDrawable.setSizeAndOffset(dimension.size.x, dimension.size.y, dimension.offset.x, dimension.offset.y);
                rectDrawable.setColor(mProducts.get(i).color);
                rectDrawable.draw(canvas);
            }


        }
    }

    public interface DimensionResolveStrategy {

        public List<Dimension> calculateDimensions(Canvas canvas, List<? extends DrawInstructionHolder> items, int columns);
    }
```